# Server Error in '/' Application. In AppHarbour

Tags: web-config, appharbor

I have deployed a MVC project in AppHarbour but it is giving some errors in some pages when i move from one controller to other [Link with error](http://nationaldatavisualization-1.apphb.com/Home/Index) and [Link without error](http://nationaldatavisualization-1.apphb.com)

And Error is..

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
    <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```